# How can I avoid a request to the root of a website going through ASP.NET, and simply return index.html?

Tags: asp.net, iis

When I go to the root of my ASP.NET website, the request goes into the ASP.NET pipeline and then returns index.html.

Is there a way in web.config to configure this so that IIS simply returns the file without going into the ASP.NET pipeline?

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Global.asax:

```
using System.Web;

namespace Test
{
    public class Global : HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_BeginRequest()
        {
            var url = this.Request.Url;
        }
    }
}
```

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set **runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests=false** inside web.config. It has other side effects, but can give a try first.

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false" />
</system.webServer>
```